# Evaluating $\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{\left(2x^2-1\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{x-1}\right)$ Without L'Hopital or Calculus?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

What is: $\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{\left(2x^2-1\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{x-1}\right)$?

Thanks in advance

Much appreciated!

Comment: Consider the series expansion of the numerator about $x=1$, as shown [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+%282x%5E2-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29-x%5E%281%2F2%29+about+x%3D1&a=%5E_Real)

Comment: Does dividing each term by $x$ count as L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: This problem is from a book, where "Limits" is an introduction to Calculus

Comment: @Ethan: it would be better to add this information to the question, and perhaps even describe what is being covered in the section where the question is presented so that we know what topics are being explained.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It mostly depends on what you're allowed to use. In order to do it without recurring to derivatives, I'd split it into two parts:
\begin{align}
\lim _{x\to 1}\biggl(\frac{(2x^2-1)^{1/3}-x^{1/2}}{x-1}\biggr)
&=\lim _{x\to 1}\biggl(\frac{(2x^2-1)^{1/3}-1+1-x^{1/2}}{x-1}\biggr)
\\[6px]
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{(2x^2-1)^{1/3}-1}{x-1}-
\frac{x^{1/2}-1}{x-1}\right) \\[6px]
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{(2x^2-1)^{1/3}-1}{x-1}-
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{1/2}-1}{x-1}
\end{align}
provided both limits in the last expression exist (they do). The second one is easy: multiply by $x^{1/2}+1$ to get
$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{1/2}-1}{x-1}=
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x-1}{(x-1)(x^{1/2}+1)}=
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{x^{1/2}+1}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

The first one can be treated in a similar way recalling that
$$
a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)
$$
where $a=(2x^2-1)^{1/3}$ and $b=1$.

Comment: Really neat idea ! (+1)

Comment: @egreg Your try is nice, but there is one problem. You are partially substituting $x=1$ in the limit, i.e. in case of $\sqrt{x}$ whereas in the rest of the limit you continue with $x$-terms to come to an answer. That's not appropriate. Did you check answers of others? They have something else

Comment: @imranfat I don't understand; in the explicit computation I assume having canceled the factor $x-1$, so substituting $x=1$ is legal. However, I added the “missing” step.

Comment: @egreg i feel that imranfat is (wrongly) saying that you used $\lim_{x→ 1} f(x,\sqrt{x}) = \lim_{x→ 1} f(x,1)$, before computing either of the 2 limits.

Comment: @egreg I think I get it now, you subtracted and added $1$. It is clearer now...

Comment: @egreg  Got it (finally...)

Comment: @imranfat I added the intermediate steps; better avoiding too many implicit steps if somebody has doubts about them. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\left(2x^2-1\right)^{\frac13}-x^{\frac12}}{x-1}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\left(2x^2+4x+1\right)^{\frac13}-(x+1)^{\frac12}}{x}\tag{1}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\left(2x^2+4x+1\right)^{\frac13}-1}{x}-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x+1)^{\frac12}-1}{x}\tag{2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x^2+4x}{x\left(\left(2x^2+4x+1\right)^{\frac23}+\left(2x^2+4x+1\right)^{\frac13}+1\right)}\tag{3}\\
&-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{x\left((x+1)^{\frac12}+1\right)}\tag{4}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x+4}{\left(2x^2+4x+1\right)^{\frac23}+\left(2x^2+4x+1\right)^{\frac13}+1}\tag{5}\\
&-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{(x+1)^{\frac12}+1}\tag{6}\\
&=\frac43-\frac12\tag{7}\\[3pt]
&=\frac56\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x\mapsto x+1$
$(2)$: subtract and add $1$ to the numerator so that we can split the limit into two
$(3)$: multiply and divide by $\left(2x^2+4x+1\right)^{\frac23}+\left(2x^2+4x+1\right)^{\frac13}+1$
$(4)$: multiply and divide by $(x+1)^{\frac12}+1$
$(5)$: cancel $x$ in numerator and denominator
$(6)$: cancel $x$ in numerator and denominator
$(7)$: evaluate $(5)$ and $(6)$ at $x=0$
$(8)$: simplify

Comment: Which is basically the same as my answer, only fully spelled out.

Comment: @egreg: I'm sorry if I my approach is similar to yours, but when I first saw the question, your answer was so abbreviated that I did not realize it was similar. Of course, there are not many pre-calculus approaches.

Comment: @egreg: now that the question has been closed for lack of context, it has a decent chance of being deleted. Oh, well.

Answer (score 3):

We can expand the terms in the numerator as

$$(2x^2-1)^{1/3}=1+\frac43(x-1)+O(x-1)^2 \tag 1$$

and

$$x^{1/2}=1+\frac12(x-1)+O(x-1)^2 \tag2$$

Subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$ and passing to the limit we find

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{(2x^2-1)^{1/3}-x^{1/2}}{x-1}=\frac43-\frac12=\frac56$$

To verify, L'Hospital's Rule comes to the rescue.  We have

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{(2x^2-1)^{1/3}-x^{1/2}}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac13(2x^2-1)^{-2/3}4x-\frac12 x^{-1/2}\right)=\frac56$$